# Escaping HTML in Marionette collection view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I can't seem to find how to properly escape content when using a Marionette Collection view.
**Although this does work properly for Backbone with jQuery**, I can't seem to find a solution for Marionette.

I tried the following:

```
<%- name %>
```

Where name = `<Zwoop`.
This does not work: it renders an empty string.
I realise that this is not valid HTML after a previous question, but it doesn't explain how I can solve the problem if the above syntax doesn't work as expected.

Escaping with underscore manually on the itemview's initialize method also results in an empty string in the browser:

```
    initialize: function(){ 
        this.model.set("name", _.escape(this.model.get("name"))); 
        console.log(this.model.toJSON()); 
    },
```

Although the model properly shows that the content is escaped:

[image]

[image]

I'm getting pretty annoyed by this problem as I'm wasting too much time on it, but it is crucial on the level of security.
(I cleared the browser cache, so that's also not the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping in Marionette works fine.

```js
var ExampleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: '<Zwoop'
  }
});

var ExampleItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: _.template('<%- name %>'),
  model: new ExampleModel()
});

var ExampleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: ExampleModel
});

var ExampleCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  childView: ExampleItemView,
  template: _.template(''),
  collection: new ExampleCollection([{}])
});

$('body').append((new ExampleCollectionView()).render().el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="http://marionettejs.com/downloads/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
```

Comment: It came from an unexpected corner. The problem lies with the selectBoxIt dropdown plugin. With a normal selectbox, it works normally.

Comment: Also, it lies partially with the tpl plugin for loading templates from other files. The <%-value%> syntax does not appear to work. It does work with a regular underscore template though. Annoying problems.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it:

```
<%- _.escape(name) %>
```

Works!

Very oddly enough, it needs to be escaped twice.
The initialize method is also required:

```
    initialize: function(){ 
        this.model.set("name", _.escape(this.model.get("name"))); 
    },
```

Although this seems non-sensical to me, trying with either one fails.
I have to use them both in order to be displayed (?!).

Comment: This doesn't seem correct to me. Underscore's _.template calls _.escape when using <%- value %>. You can see for yourself here: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1398

Give me a sec to play with this in a codepen.

Comment: Quite frankly, it doesn't make sense to me at all. I double checked all possibilities, and the syntax <%- value %> does not work for me, it renders all empty strings.

Comment: I provided a solution, but it's not clear to me what problem you were encountering as the solution worked as expected?

Comment: See comment to your answer for info -> sad hack, but luckily it's currently solved with the way I currently fixed it. Since I'm working against a deadline eoy, unfortunately I don't have the time to look for a better dropdown solution currenlty. Thanks for your help.